# Copy a static field

Tags: c#, static

I have a class in which I operate some methods.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static List<ObjectA> MyField;

  public static Object MyMethod()
  {
      List<ObjectA> anotherObjectA = new List<ObjectA>();
      // I do something with anotherObjectA...
      // after processing something now I want to keep the current status of                anotherObjectA to MyField:
      MyField = anotherObjectA;
      // and now I want to work just with anotherObjectA. The problem is that whatever   I work with anotherObjectA it changes also MyField 

 }
}
```

How can i achieve what I am trying to do

Comment: `MyField` and `anotherObjectA` reference the same object. You should create two objects.

Comment: I have tried to create public static List<ObjectA> MyField = new List<ObjectA>(); But still same

Comment: List is a reference type. so making a copy like you do will add a second reference to the same object. You need to create a new object `MyField = anotherObjectA.ToList()`

Comment: But the problem is that whenever I change something in anotherObjectA then MyField changes also.

Comment: No, MyField does not change. But the list that MyField is referencing is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyField` and `anotherObjectA` reference same object. So if you change `MyField` it also changes `anotherObjectA`.

So First you need to create two List objects:

```
MyField = new List<ObjectA>(anotherObjectA);
```

This will create two list objects but the `ObjectA` objects inside the list are still referencing to the same.

```
MyField.First() == anotherObjectA.First() // returns true;
```

If you want to make a complete copy you also need to create a copy of objects inside `anotherObjectA`

```
public class ObjectA
{
   public ObjectA() { } // Normal constructor
   public ObjectA(ObjectA objToCopy) { /* copy fields into new object */ }
}

MyField = anotherObjectA.Select(obja => new ObjectA(obja)).ToList();
```

with this solution, changing objects inside `MyField` will not affect objects inside `anotherObjectA` unless ObjectA also contains reference types.

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
MyField = new List<ObjectA>(anotherObjectA);
```

This will create a copy of the list. However, any changes to the objects in the list will be visible in both. You'll have to decide for yourself how deep your copy has to be. If you really want a deep copy, you'll need to provide a mechanism for `ObjectA` to make a copy of itself, iterate over the original list, and add a copy of each object to the target list.